# Best way to handle a lot of different background tasks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, delayed-job, background-process, resque

We have to run in the background a lot of different tasks, including:

- Video Transcoding
- Video Uploads to S3
- Create Objects in third-party APIs
- Grab Statistics from third-party APIs (every midnight)
- [....]

I was forecasting to do everything myself. However, a friend of mine points me to `Resque` which seems interesting minus the overwork to have `redis` running. I have started to look also to `delayed_job` and `sidekick`, the latter seems to not active development.

This background tasks are your core business. I guess it's important for us to be able to debug easily and have detailled report about failed tasks. So, I don't mind spending a lot of time on it. I was wondering if someone has already confronted to this kind of issues and what's the prefered path to choose?

Our current Stack is rails, mongoid, mongoDB on dedicated ubuntu servers.

Comment: There's no single right answer to this.  You've already mentioned the big three in this space, and seem to have done a fair bit of research.  Resque is probably winning the popularity contest right now, and is well-supported by Heroku, and actively developed, so it has a lot going for it.  Running Redis is a small price to pay; it's easy to setup and fairly unobtrusive.

Comment: I see, so your preference seems to go towards Resque?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with any of them to endorse one.  I like to check [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) to compare gems and see how active they are and what the community is using and why.  It's a good starting point for further research.

Comment: Cool thanks! Sometimes, I feel you made bad choice based on popularity of the project, ie when you don't need that level of complexity